# UITableView confusion

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I’m confused. I have a dynamic `tableView` to display my data and a `loadData()` method where I basically load data from a JSON into a `tableViewModel`. Now I’ve been wanting to resolve duplication of data each time the table updates or refreshes, for which I implemented:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        // To avoid duplication of data when the table updates or refreshes.
        self.tableViewModel.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    }
```

The issue was resolved. Now when I switch between my views, and get back to the `tableView`, it gives me the `index out of range` error. I’ve tried reloading my `tableView` after `self.tableViewModel.removeAll` but that just reloads the empty `tableView` for me as the `tableViewModel` is empty. If I call `loadData()` after `self.tableViewModel.removeAll`, it starts duplicating my data again.

How can I resolve this? And how should I make good use of `viewDidDisappear`, `viewDidAppear`, `viewWillDisappear`, `viewWillAppear` without duplicating my data and also save myself from the `index out range` error?

Comment: What is the type of `tableViewModel`? If it is a type you created, can you show how it is defined? Also show the datasource methods because the index out of range thing is likely to be caused in there.

Comment: Could you post full error message and all functions related to `UITableViewDataSource` delegate? How do you load the data? I am not quite sure what `tableViewModel` you mentioned is.

The problem probably is in `func tableView(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int)` or in the `tableViewModel` . 

You should prepare data in `viewWillAppear` if the data is dynamical. And prepare data in `viewDidLoad` if the data is fixed.

Comment: @Sweeper tableViewModel is a struct that I’ve defined as `init(json: NSDictionary)`. There’s a lot that I’m going to need to post here if you want me to post all the datasource methods. But as far as I know, the error is likely in the numberOfRowsInSection. I’ve implemented that as: return tableViewModel.count . Though, I’ve fixed the issue, if you still have any best practices, that’d be great.

Comment: @EricZhang it’s `fatal error: Index out of range`. I was advised not to prepare data in `viewWillAppear` as it duplicates my data each time the view appears. I use Firebase for my database and it loads the data each time the data changes. So when I prepare my data in `viewWillAppear`, that is what duplicates my data. The data is loaded as JSON, saved in the tableViewModel as NSDictionary and then populating the tableView.

Comment: @waseefakhtar Interesting. I am wondering how the `tableViewModel` works. Let's say you have data ["A", "B", "C"], then you add a "D". Will the `tableViewModel` contain ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "D"]? In my option, if `tableViewModel` works fine, `tableViewModel.count` should always return correct number. (3 for "A","B","C"; 4 for "A", "B", "C", "D").  It is impossible to show duplicate data no matter where and when you load the data.

Comment: @waseefakhtar According your implementation in `viewDidDisappear`, it seems that `tableViewModel` can "notice"  a change happened in database but is not able to "recognize" what data it already fetched.

Comment: @EricZhang yes, the tableView would duplicate data like ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "D”] if I load data in viewDidAppear, and not ["A", "B", "C", "D”]. You’re certainly right about tableViewModel noticing a change in database but not being able to recognize the existing data. What do you think is the best practice here?

Comment: @waseefakhtar Is it possible to let `tableViewModel` inherit from `Set` instead of `Array`? You know, `Set` never has duplicate data.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked by changing the place of `self.tableViewModel.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)` from `viewDidDisappear` to my l`oadData()` method as:

```
func loadData() {
        // To avoid duplication of data when the table updates or refreshes.
        self.tableViewModel.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        print("Table View Model Cleared: \(self.tableViewModel)”)

        // Now load data from the internet.
}
```

What this did is refreshing the tableView with new data each time `loadData()` is called so that the tableView doesn’t keep the old data and duplicating it with the new ones.

This also saves me from the `fatal error: Index out of range` as `removeAll` and loading data take place in one method rather than two separate. When I had placed `removeAll` in `viewDidDisappear`, it’d clean the `tableViewModel` each time I switched to another view and upon switching back, it’d get lost in:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {    

        return tableViewModel.count
    }
```

In my opinion, The `fatal error: Index out of range` tells us that the number of rows in our tableView does not match the number of posts in the tableViewModel. And that is exactly what we return in `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Any suggestions and best practices would be greatly appreciated. Also, correct me anywhere that I’m wrong.

Comment: normally you get an array from the datasource `var dataArray = Repositor.getXxxxxTableDataModel()` and after some possible modifications then you can set this direct to to `self.tableViewModel = dataArray` in your load data (and not apped it) then you not need `removeAll`